# SQL - Joining two Select results horizontal

Tags: mysql, join

I am creating the following two temporary tables t1 and t2 using two SELECT statements:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
| A    |    1 |
| B    |    2 |
| C    |    3 |
+------+------+
```

and

```
+------+------+
| Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+
| C    |    5 |
| D    |    6 |
| E    |    7 |
+------+------+
```

The two SELECT statements by nature are always returning the same number of rows. Now I want to join/combine these two results horizontally to get the following output table:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| A    |    1 | C    |    5 |
| B    |    2 | D    |    6 |
| C    |    3 | E    |    7 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

I tried working with multiple JOIN statement, but could figure out a smart way. I also tried the UNION statement, which delivered a vertical join, but not the required horizontal version.

Here two easy SELECT statement for better orientation in possible solutions:

```
SELECT * FROM `t1` WHERE date = DATE(NOW())

SELECT * FROM `t2` WHERE date = DATE(NOW())
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need a _relation_ to join these two tables "horizontally."  What is the relationship between `Col2` and `Col4` (if there is one)?

Comment: That exactly my tricky point.
Maybe to add a bit more details: The two SELECT statements are ordering the data and I would like to combine the two tables in this order. Is there any way without having to creat a new identifier?

Comment: Would `Col4` = `Col2` + 4 be meaningful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SET @row_number_t1:=0;
SET @row_number_t2:=0;

SELECT t1_modif.*, t2_modif.* FROM 
    (SELECT @row_number_t1:=@row_number_t1+1 AS row_number,
            t1.* FROM t1) 
    t1_modif
JOIN (SELECT @row_number_t2:=@row_number_t2+1 AS row_number,
            t2.* FROM t2) 
    t2_modif ON t2_modif.row_number = t1_modif.row_number
```

Note that order is not guaranteed, to do this add `ORDER BY` clause at the end of each `FROM t1` and `FROM t2` subqueries, basically we are joining by row_number, since MySQL doesn't have ROW_ID, ROW_NUM (similar to mssql, oracle, postgres) we have used session variables

Answer (score 0):

Creating Virtual IDs for relation. This is not a recommended way though.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM 
    (SELECT t1.*, (@t1VID := @t1VID + 1) t1VID  FROM t1 , (SELECT @t1VID := 0) d) e 
        JOIN (SELECT t2.*, (@t2VID := @t2VID + 1) t2VID FROM t2, (SELECT @t2VID := 0) a ) b ON t1VID  = t2VID
        JOIN (SELECT @t1VID := 0) c ;
```

Ideal solution would have been adding proper relation between the tables. If not, it is best to query it separately and do the necessary joining in application layer